# Group by error in a sql server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem with my sql server query

```
SELECT TOP 100 tblCallEnd.CallListID,
               tblCallList.CLI,
               tblCallEnd.CreateDate,
               tblCallEnd.IsLost,
               tblCallEnd.SOLUCIONADO,
               tblCallEnd.TIEMPO,
               tblCallEnd.DestroyDate,
               tblHuntGroup.Name AS grupo,
               farmacia.farmacia AS farmacia,

  (SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, tbe.CreateDate, tbe.DestroyDate))
   FROM tblCallEnd tbe
   WHERE tbe.CallListID = tblCallEnd.CallListID
     AND tbe.IEndFlag = 1
   GROUP BY tbe.CallListID) AS TiempoTotal
FROM tblCallEnd
INNER JOIN tblCallList ON tblCallEnd.CallListID = tblCallList.CallListID
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblHuntGroup ON tblCallEnd.hgid = tblHuntGroup.HGID
LEFT OUTER JOIN farmacia ON farmacia.tfn = tblCallList.cli
WHERE tblCallEnd.IsLost = 0
  AND tblCallEnd.SOLUCIONADO IS NOT NULL
  AND DATEPART(yy, tblCallEnd.TIEMPO) = '2013'
  AND DATEPART(mm, tblCallEnd.TIEMPO) = '12'
  AND DATEPART(dd, tblCallEnd.TIEMPO) = '10'
GROUP BY tblCallEnd.CallListID
ORDER BY tblCallEnd.TIEMPO DESC
```

I need to group by the column tblCallEnd.CallListID but i recieve this error:

La columna 'tblCallList.CLI' de la lista de selección no es válida, porque no está contenida en una función de agregado ni en la cláusula GROUP BY.

Comment: no need for GROUP BY tblCallEnd.CallListID

Comment: If you read the error carefully it says, you have to include 'tblCallList.CLI' column in GROUP BY. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I recieve a lot of results with the same tblCallEnd.CallListID and i need to group only by this column. If i add tblCallList.CLI to group_by y recieve the same error with tblCallEnd.CreateDate column

Comment: @50l3r : Why you need `group by` without having any `aggregation` functions??

Answer (score 0):

GROUP BY must contain all columns from select that are not used in an aggregate function.

```
select sum(col1), col2, col3 from Table
Group by col2, col3
```

In your case, you don't use any aggregate function, so GROUP BY cannot be used. Maybe you want to use order by like

```
ORDER BY tblCallEnd.CallListID, tblCallEnd.TIEMPO DESC
```